# Passing variables to a PoSh remote file to execute

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to run a PS Remote session from Machine A to access Machine B. Both are on the same domain and Kerberos authentication is working and I can establish a PS Remote session.

I am trying to run a script from Machine A on MAchine B passing parameters to that script as follows:

```
$build_script_dir = Resolve-Path .
$file_to_execute = "$build_script_dir\file_to_execute.ps1"

invoke-command -ComputerName MachineB -FilePath $file_to_execute -argumentlist $Arg1,$Arg2,$Arg3,$Arg4
```

This doesn't seem to invoke the script. I have even tried to take the script to the remote machine and then execute it that way as follows:

```
$remote_file = "c:\path-to-file\remote_file.ps1"

invoke-command -ComputerName MachineB -ScriptBlock {$remote_file} -argumentlist $Arg1,$Arg2,$Arg3,$Arg4
```

What am I missing that is stopping the script from running? I have about 10 arguments to pass to the script and the script will manipulate IIS.

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the script exists only on the remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -scriptBlock { C:\scripts\Test.PS1 "Arguments here"}
```

`-FilePath` looks for the script on local machine.

When you specify the filepath inside `-ScriptBlock`, you can invoke a script residing on remote system.

Also, if you need to pass any variables from local machine to remote script, use the -Argumentlist. But, the `-ScriptBlock` requires a param(). For example,

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -scriptBlock { param($name, $age) C:\scripts\Test.PS1 -Name $name -Age $age} -ArgumentList $name,$age
```

In the above command, $name and $age are the local variables.

Comment: I have a list of about 15 parameters - do I need to assign them all in the param() or could I possibly use a PSObject?

Comment: Send a hash to the remote script and use -Property to use that hash in the script.